# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' when I refactor my application by modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I had everything in my app in the single app.module.ts file, everything was working perfectly, however, I'm trying to refactor everything by modules (core, shared, feature) but I'm having an error in my feature component that uses a reactive form

`Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.`

I'm guessing it's an error with the imports, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong exactly.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RxReactiveFormsModule } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

/* App modules */
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RxReactiveFormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**core.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RegisterService } from './services/auth/register.service';
import { LoginService } from './services/auth/login.service';
import { RecoveryService } from './services/auth/recovery.service';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    RegisterService,
    LoginService,
    RecoveryService
  ]
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    if (parentModule){
      throw new Error(
        'CoreModule is already loaded. Import it in AppModule only'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { PrimengModule } from './primeng.module';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from '../core/errors/not-found/not-found.component';
import { ServerDisconnectedComponent } from '../core/errors/server-disconnected/server-disconnected.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavigationComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    ServerDisconnectedComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PrimengModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**auth.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { AuthRoutingModule } from './auth-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './register/account/account.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './register/contact/contact.component';
import { StatusComponent } from './register/status/status.component';
import { FamilyComponent } from './register/family/family.component';
import { RecoveryComponent } from './recovery/recovery.component';
import { ChangeComponent } from './recovery/change/change.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    StatusComponent,
    FamilyComponent,
    RecoveryComponent,
    ChangeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    AuthRoutingModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `FormsModule` (and probably `ReactiveFormsModule`) in each module that uses `formGroup`, I'm not sure which is your feature module, but that's the module in which the import is missing